# Slow ssh login after upgrade to bookworm

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have just upgraded to bookworm from bullseye on a Raspi 3B+-32bit.
Everything is fine, but ssh login to another Raspberry became inexplicably slow.

This is my ssh_config (pretty standard):

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP no
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

When logging in (with option -vv) I see that it take long time on this line, but I don't understand why:

```
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
```

Comment: "upgraded from bookworm on a Raspi 3B+-32bit" did you do a fresh install as recommended?

Comment: No: upgraded. But now everything is fixed

Comment: edited the wording. to bookworm from bullseye

Comment: So you chose to ignore "This time, because the changes to the underlying architecture are so significant, we are not suggesting any procedure for upgrading a Bullseye image to Bookworm; any attempt to do this will almost certainly end up with a non-booting desktop and data loss" - expect more problems.

Comment: Yes, and it is happily working. What's your point?  And, despite your nice wishes, I am not expecting any other problem.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html

Comment: What does amd64 have to do with the Pi?

Comment: ..and what your comments have to do with the original question (which has been solved)?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem by adding this line to my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp521
```

Sharing for anyone having same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Massive thanks for this! I have the exact same symptom from the exact same update. And configuring that KexAlgorithms severely speeds up the connection setup time.

Also I found that this setting impacts the time much more on a raspberry (~ factor 10) than on other platforms (~ factor 2-3, tested on several amd64 SBCs).

How did you figure out this approach? I'm asking because I'd like to get some more indepth information on this.

Comment: How? Two full days of working and studying the "secrets" of KexAlgorythms...:-(
It wasn't easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I bet so ;). Thanks again for your time and effort! If you have some URLs from your research I'd still be interested to dig into. However (unlike the bot) I also totally understand that this might be asked too much ;)